podman pull issue RHEL9 : Error: initializing source docker:
I am trying to pull a image using the below command in my local VM first time. It throws the below error. The system is subscribed to RHEL9. Please advise

#podman pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi Trying to pull
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest... WARN[0040] Failed,
retrying in 1s ... (1/3). Error: initializing source
docker://registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest: pinging container
registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get
"https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": dial tcp: lookup
registry.access.redhat.com on 192.168.253.2:53: read udp
192.168.253.140:46271->192.168.253.2:53: i/o timeout

Executed with debug level also

[joe@node1 ~]$ podman pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi
--log-level debug INFO[0000] podman filtering at log level debug           DEBU[0000] Called pull.PersistentPreRunE(podman pull
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi --log-level debug)  DEBU[0000]
Using conmon: "/usr/bin/conmon"               INFO[0000] Using sqlite
as database backend              DEBU[0000] Using graph driver overlay
DEBU[0000] Using graph root /home/joe/.local/share/containers/storage
DEBU[0000] Using run root /run/user/1001/containers      DEBU[0000]
Using static dir /home/joe/.local/share/containers/storage/libpod
DEBU[0000] Using tmp dir /run/user/1001/libpod/tmp       DEBU[0000]
Using volume path /home/joe/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
DEBU[0000] Using transient store: false                  DEBU[0000]
[graphdriver] trying provided driver "overlay"  DEBU[0000] Cached
value indicated that overlay is supported  DEBU[0000] Cached value
indicated that overlay is supported  DEBU[0000] Cached value indicated
that metacopy is not being used  DEBU[0000] Cached value indicated
that native-diff is usable  DEBU[0000] backingFs=xfs,
projectQuotaSupported=false, useNativeDiff=true, usingMetacopy=false
DEBU[0000] Initializing event backend file               DEBU[0000]
Configured OCI runtime runc initialization failed: no valid executable
found for OCI runtime runc: invalid argument  DEBU[0000] Configured
OCI runtime runj initialization failed: no valid executable found for
OCI runtime runj: invalid argument  DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime
runsc initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime
runsc: invalid argument  DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime youki
initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime
youki: invalid argument  DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime ocijail
initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime
ocijail: invalid argument  DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime crun-wasm
initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime
crun-wasm: invalid argument  DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime kata
initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime kata:
invalid argument  DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime krun
initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime krun:
invalid argument  DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime crun-vm
initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime
crun-vm: invalid argument  DEBU[0000] Using OCI runtime
"/usr/bin/crun"             INFO[0000] Setting parallel job count to 7
DEBU[0000] Pulling image registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi (policy:
always)  DEBU[0000] Looking up image
"registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi" in local containers storage
DEBU[0000] Normalized platform linux/amd64 to {amd64 linux  [] }
DEBU[0000] Trying "registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest" ...
DEBU[0000] reference
"[overlay@/home/joe/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1001/containers]registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest" does not resolve to an image ID  DEBU[0000] Trying
"registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest" ...  DEBU[0000] reference
"[overlay@/home/joe/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1001/containers]registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest" does not resolve to an image ID  DEBU[0000] Trying
"registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi" ...  DEBU[0000] Loading
registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf"  DEBU[0000]
Loading registries configuration
"/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf"  DEBU[0000]
Loading registries configuration
"/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/001-rhel-shortnames.conf"
DEBU[0000] Loading registries configuration
"/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/002-rhel-shortnames-overrides.conf"
DEBU[0000] Normalized platform linux/amd64 to {amd64 linux  [] }
DEBU[0000] Attempting to pull candidate
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest for
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi  DEBU[0000] parsed reference into
"[overlay@/home/joe/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1001/containers]registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest"  Trying to pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest...
DEBU[0000] Copying source image
//registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest to destination image
[overlay@/home/joe/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1001/containers]registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest
DEBU[0000] Using registries.d directory /etc/containers/registries.d
DEBU[0000] Trying to access
"registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest"  DEBU[0000] No
credentials matching registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi found in
/run/user/1001/containers/auth.json  DEBU[0000] No credentials
matching registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi found in
/home/joe/.config/containers/auth.json  DEBU[0000] No credentials
matching registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi found in
/home/joe/.docker/config.json  DEBU[0000] No credentials matching
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi found in /home/joe/.dockercfg
DEBU[0000] No credentials for registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi
found  DEBU[0000]  Lookaside configuration: using "docker" namespace
registry.access.redhat.com  DEBU[0000]   Using "sigstore"
https://access.redhat.com/webassets/docker/content/sigstore
DEBU[0000] Looking for TLS certificates and private keys in
/etc/docker/certs.d/registry.access.redhat.com  DEBU[0000]  Sigstore
attachments: using "docker" namespace registry.access.redhat.com
DEBU[0000] GET https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/    DEBU[0020]
Ping https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/ err Get
"https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": dial tcp: lookup
registry.access.redhat.com on 192.168.253.2:53: read udp
192.168.253.140:38411->192.168.253.2:53: i/o timeout (&url.Error{Op:"Get", URL:"https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/",
Err:(*net.OpError)(0xc000440140)})  DEBU[0020] GET
https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping  DEBU[0040] Ping
https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping err Get
"https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping": dial tcp: lookup
registry.access.redhat.com on 192.168.253.2:53: read udp
192.168.253.140:36770->192.168.253.2:53: i/o timeout (&url.Error{Op:"Get",
URL:"https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping",
Err:(*net.OpError)(0xc0002bc410)})  DEBU[0040] Accessing
"registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest" failed: pinging container
registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get
"https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": dial tcp: lookup
registry.access.redhat.com on 192.168.253.2:53: read udp
192.168.253.140:38411->192.168.253.2:53: i/o timeout  WARN[0040] Failed, retrying in 1s ... (1/3). Error: initializing source
docker://registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest: pinging container
registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get
"https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": dial tcp: lookup
registry.access.redhat.com on 192.168.253.2:53: read udp
192.168.253.140:38411->192.168.253.2:53: i/o timeout  DEBU[0041] Using registries.d directory /etc/containers/registries.d  DEBU[0041] Trying
to access "registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest"  DEBU[0041] No
credentials matching registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi found in
/run/user/1001/containers/auth.json  DEBU[0041] No credentials
matching registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi found in
/home/joe/.config/containers/auth.json  DEBU[0041] No credentials
matching registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi found in
/home/joe/.docker/config.json  DEBU[0041] No credentials matching
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi found in /home/joe/.dockercfg
DEBU[0041] No credentials for registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi
found  DEBU[0041]  Lookaside configuration: using "docker" namespace
registry.access.redhat.com  DEBU[0041]   Using "sigstore"
https://access.redhat.com/webassets/docker/content/sigstore
DEBU[0041] Looking for TLS certificates and private keys in
/etc/docker/certs.d/registry.access.redhat.com  DEBU[0041]  Sigstore
attachments: using "docker" namespace registry.access.redhat.com
DEBU[0041] GET https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/    DEBU[0061]
Ping https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/ err Get
"https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": dial tcp: lookup
registry.access.redhat.com on 192.168.253.2:53: read udp
192.168.253.140:52105->192.168.253.2:53: i/o timeout (&url.Error{Op:"Get", URL:"https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/",
Err:(*net.OpError)(0xc00048e640)})  DEBU[0061] GET
https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping


Found the solution .. When I changed my VMWare workstation network setting to Bridged from NAT it started working. Though in NAT also I was able to access internet.
